# How to store a struct as a linked list Node and this struct has char *words[10] which is a parsed string?

Tags: c, string, linked-list

More specific to my question is, I want to store a struct words in a linked list, and each node has **char *words[10]**, this **char *words[10]** comes from a parsed string, each words[i] is a word in this string(first 10 words).

I have a string(in my question, the string is "I am jersey."), and want to store each word in it into my struct, specifically, words[0] stores "I", words[1] stores "am" and words[2] stores "jersey.". However, what I store in it is not a word, but NULL. How to solve this problem?

In addition, in ***the struct words * parse_string*** function, its third part seems to have some problems as well. When I debug it, the buffer store each char in it, which are 'I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' '....Is it correct?

My code is attached as following.

Here is my .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hwTest.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct words *w1 = NULL;
    int i;
    char *str = "I am jersey.";

    w1 = parse_string(" ", str);

    for(i = 0; i < w1->count; i++){
        printf("  [%d] = \"%s\"", i, w1->words[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

struct words *parse_string(char *delimiter, char *string){
    //first allocate memory space;
    // Head pointer doesn't need to store data, it's used for iterating;
    words *wordsHead = (words *)calloc(1, sizeof(words));
    wordsHead->next = NULL;

    //Second, copy the input *string to the buffer field in struct words;
    strcpy(wordsHead->buffer,string); //这里就出现了问题：存储在buffer中的是‘I’ ‘ ’ ‘a’...

    //Third, use strtok to parse the contents of buffer into up to 10 words, delimited by the character in the string
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x<10; x++){
        char *temp = strtok(wordsHead->buffer, delimiter);
        if(temp == NULL){
            //When we finished, set int x to "words->count"
            wordsHead->count = x;
            break;
        }
        //Store individual word from "words" in "wordHead->words[x]" where x represents the index.
        wordsHead->words[x] = temp;

        // Finally, returns pointers to following words;
        strtok(wordsHead->buffer,NULL); /*pass NULL to 2nd and following calls*/
    }

    return wordsHead;
}
```

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef hwTest_h
#define hwTest_h


typedef struct words{
    // for a linked list;
    struct words *next;

    //to store the string to be parsed;
    char buffer[128];

    //number of words(up to 10);
    int count;

    //pointers to up to 10 words;
    char *words[10];

} words;

struct words *parse_string(char *delimiter, char *string);



#endif /* hwTest_h */
```

Comment: 1. You are not actually using a linked list in the example given. All the data is being stored in a single variable of type struct. `wordsHead`   2. While storing to the array of pointers `wordsHead->words[x]` you should use `wordsHead->words[x] = strdup(temp);`

Comment: If you want to use a linked list then the structure definitions need to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(x = 0; x<10; x++){
    char *temp = strtok(wordsHead->buffer, delimiter);
    // ...
    strtok(wordsHead->buffer,NULL); 
}
```

This is a wrong way to extract tokens from a buffer. Change this to

```
char *temp = strtok(wordsHead->buffer, delimiter);
for(x = 0; x<10; x++) {
   // ...
   strtok(NULL, delimiter); 
}
```

Pay attention to which argument of `strtok` changes to `NULL`.